# How to change URL format with 2 parameters to clean URLs in a subdirectory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

Banging my head over the wall and can't find an appropriate solution.

I have the following htaccess code in my root/main directory:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

</IfModule>
```

Then i have a subdirectory called /classic-wow/ .

In it, I have a file called buy-account.php?id=12345&ad=advertising-title

I seek a solution that will turn the url into: buy-account/12345/advertising-title

So far, the htaccess in the main/root directory is omitting the .php which is good, however, I am unable to convert the parameters into a clean url ?id=12345&ad=advertising-title -> /12345/advertising-title

How to do this? Is additional .htaccess required in the subdirectory classic /root/classic-wow/ or it can be done from the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `classic-wow/.htaccess`, you may use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(buy-account)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&ad=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Assuming i can now use $_GET['id'] and $_GET['ad'] to retrieve the variables.